# How can I extract billing details from card element during button onClick?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

We have the following function that runs when our stripe Start Subscription button is clicked:

```
    const handleSubmit = async (ev) => {
        setIsProcessing(true);
        const cardElement = elements.getElement('card');
        try {
            // Grab Stripe Elements + Variables needed to post payment subscription
            cardElement.update({ disabled: true });
            const apiBaseUrl = config.url.API_URL;
            const id = userData.user ? userData.user._id : null;

            // Grab Billing (zip only) & Create Payment Method
            const billingDetails = {
                address: {
                    postal_code: ev.target.zip.value
                }
            };
            const paymentMethodReq = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: billingDetails
            });

            // Handle Creating Payment Subscription
            if (paymentMethodReq.error) { ... return } // handle bad payment
            const paymentObject = { id, paymentMethod: paymentMethodReq.paymentMethod.id }; // address
            const response = await Axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/stripe/payment_subscriptions`, paymentObject);
            setIsProcessing(false);
        } catch (error) {
            ... handle error
        }
    };
```

and our subscribe button that calls the `handleSubmit` function

```
            <button
                className='stripe-button'
                onClick={handleSubmit}
                disabled={isProcessing || !stripe}
            >
                Start Subscription
            </button>
```

From our understanding of the stripe docs - https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object?lang=node - we need to pass `billing_details` into the `createPaymentMethod` function. However, `handleSubmit` throws an error because `ev.target.zip` is undefined. (I believe) since we are submitting via a button onClick (rather than a form onSubmit), that the `ev.target` does not have what we want. Here is the `console.log` for `ev`, `ev.target` and for our `cardElement`:

[image]

How can the billing details be extracted from the cardElement, from within the handleSubmit function, so that they can be passed to the `createPaymentMethod` function?

Comment: You do not need to pass in the zip code separately if you are using the CardElement.  You can just pass in the card element in this case. For example you can see this exact function being used while only passing in info on top of the zip such as the Customer's name https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously?platform=web#create-a-paymentmethod

Comment: It is also worth noting that if you are going to immediately charge the Card after you have created this PaymentMethod, it is often better to create the Subscription first and have your page call confirmPayment or confirmCardPayment on the Subscription's first Invoice's PaymentIntent. There are less moving parts with that flow so it is less prone to breaking. Stripe has a doc that models this flow if you have not seen it already https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements

Comment: @Pompey hmm okay will give that a try. We did not see the zip code info on the payment saved in Stripe's website when reviewing the payment, but perhaps we looked in wrong spot.

Comment: @Pompey confirming that the zip code doesn't appear anywhere in Stripe UI. There is an event detail with 180 lines and none of them are the zip code...

Comment: That is surprising, when I tested the createPaymentMethod function with my own code just now, the zip code was passed in by Stripe.js automatically because the card element was passing in.

Comment: Can you try making this call again while only passing in `type: card` and the `cars: cardElement` and then check your request logs[1] for a POST /v1/payment_methods call and see if a `billing_details` hash is being passed in? [1]https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs

Comment: @Pompey - ahh yes the zip code is in the `payment_methods`